# Fixing the horizontal scrollbar of a div to the bottom of a page

Tags: jquery, css, jsp, scroll

I have a table which goes longer than the length of the page rendered on the browser. That table is placed within a Div which is like

```
<Div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
```

As a result, when the contents of the page exceed the width of the table, I will have to scroll the page down using the browser scroll bar to look at the horizontal scroll bar that appears at the bottom of the above div.

I want to always fix the horizontal scroll bar of the div at the bottom of the page. So that I can scroll to the right of the table even without scrolling down.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8msx/5/) is a sample in jsFiddle

How will I do this?

Comment: can you make a demo of your situation in jsfiddle.net.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I have edited and added a jsFiddle sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its obvious. You had set `overflow: auto;` to the `div`. It will surely display a `horizontal/vertical scroll bar` whenever its `content` goes beyond its bound. If you really want to remove that scroll bar from that `div` and set it to the `browser`, just remove that piece of css from that div and simply add it to the body.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8msx/8/)