# fixed position horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a long div (let's say longer than the screen) with a horizontal scrollbar, appearing at the bottom of the div, and I would like the horizontal scrollbar to appear at the bottom of the window, not at the bottom of the div. My situation is similar to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xaTe9/1/), and I cannot really modify the layout...

Example:

```
  <p>blabla</p>
  <div id="scrolling">
    <div id="longdiv">
      <p>Looooooong looooong div, please scroll down to see the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom! If only it was <pre>position:fixed; bottom:0px;</pre>!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>blabla</p>
```

with corresponding css:

```
#scrolling {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
#longdiv {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Thank you!

**Note:** somehow the same as [Fix scrollbar to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20405680/fix-scrollbar-to-bottom) but more complete and with an example, and not similar to [Fixing the horizontal scrollbar of a div to the bottom of a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996874/fixing-the-horizontal-scrollbar-of-a-div-to-the-bottom-of-a-page) because I cannot modify my layout according to the accepted (and only) answer.

**Edit:** though I cannot find anything related to this question on google, it seems I'm not the first person to have had this problem: gmail implements such a thing. If you open a mail thread with a tiny window, there's a custom scrollbar for the div of the thread, alwas appearing at the bottom of the screen... Too bad source code is obfucated...

Comment: I'am not sure if i understood your requirement. Is this what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/xaTe9/3/ ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot change the layout to make the div scroll by itself, it must be long and scroll with the body... I really cannot change the layout, the only thing that must move is the horizontal scrollbar...

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to answer myself yet, but here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xaTe9/4/ !

Answer (score 6):

There is a nice [jQuery plugin](https://github.com/Amphiluke/floating-scroll) which takes care of this.

You can use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".yourClassName").floatingScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

set the scrolling width to larger than the longdiv. see this: http://jsfiddle.net/xaTe9/2/

```
#scrolling {
   overflow: hidden;
   width: 1500px;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: so you mean you can change html, but not css?

Comment: I mean it's by design that this div is not larger that the screen, it's actually a jquery-ui-layout pane... So I definitely cannot make it bigger than the screen...

Comment: if that is the limitation, then you can only hide the scrollbar in the div, because if the div is not larger then window, where the scrollbar come from?

Comment: I secretely hoped that there was a classical javascript pattern to do this (thought it was impossible to find any on the web). I've tried custom scrollbar jquery plugins, but none offers this feature...

Comment: sorry. can't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jQuery.Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar), look at the advanced demo examples - there is "external" scrollbar demo you need.