# How to make one column have position fixed on horizontal scroll only?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have one inline form that spans over horizontally and vertically. In this form, I have one
last column that is an add button that I want it to have a fixed position but only when I scroll the form horizontally, not vertically.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>

  <style>
    .btn-control {
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Inline form</h1>

  <div class="container" style="width: 55%; height: 500px;">
    <div class="row" style="flex-wrap: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;">
      <form style=" ">
        <div class="form-row flex-nowrap">
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Phone Numher</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Numher">
          </div>


          <div class="col-3 btn-control">
            <p></p>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-circle">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row flex-nowrap">
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Phone Numher</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Numher">
          </div>

          <div class="col-3 btn-control">
            <p></p>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-circle">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row flex-nowrap">
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Gender</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gender">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Age">
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <label for="">Phone Numher</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Numher">
          </div>

          <div class="col-3 btn-control">
            <p></p>
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-circle">+</button>
          </div>
        </div>


      </form>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

  <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have set `position: fixed` but does not solve the problem as currently, the button has fixed position on both horizontal and vertical. I found some [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22425068/fixed-position-horizontal-scrollbar), but it does not fit my need.

Thanks.

Comment: You would require JS/jQuery to identify horizontal scroll and when it is out of viewport during that event, you need to toggle the sticky class on the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[position sticky](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) should work

```
.btn-control {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
}
```

if it work you can change `right` position